# See live word count in Lualine

Tags: neovim, statusline, vimscript-lua, lua

I am currently using [lualine](https://github.com/nvim-lualine/lualine.nvim) as my statusline. I would like to see the live world count of the file similar to the feature in airline preferable I would like to get this working natively or else any **open-source** plugin is also fine.

Comment: have you asked on the lualine issue tracker for that feature?

Comment: As it is not a bug I thought against it.

Comment: Have you tried to do it by yourself? The readme says that you can use [custom components](https://github.com/nvim-lualine/lualine.nvim#custom-components) so you could create your own function which would call for example `!wc -w %` to used `wc` to count the number of words (`-w`) in your current file (`%`). You will probably get more answers if you come up with an existing code to fix :)

Comment: Thank you I tried to open an issue and turns out there is already an issue for this with code to add it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is https://github.com/nvim-lualine/lualine.nvim/issues/328. Found with help from @statox.

1. add

   ```
   local function getWords()
     return tostring(vim.fn.wordcount().words)
   end
   ```

   to whichever lua block you have your lualine config **only if using init.vim** or else if using init.lua then add anywhere.
2. Then in your lualine setup function add `{ getWords }` in whichever section you want it to appear. **The curly braces are important**. Then restart your nvim.

Comment: Could you add to your answer the code you ended up using and how you called it in your lualine function? This would make it much more useful for other users than having to check the issue and figuring out how to use the function.

Comment: Echo'ing @statox, we prefer answers to be self-contained. Keep the link, but also add any relevant explanations, quotes, etc., so that the answer is useful to other in case the link dies. You can [edit] to update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Adding on top of muppi's answer, if you want the section to change with respect to visual selection change the function to this:

```lua
local function getWords()
    -- the third string here is the string for visual-block mode (^V)
    if vim.fn.mode() == "v" or vim.fn.mode() == "V" or vim.fn.mode() == "" then
        return vim.fn.wordcount().visual_words .. " words"
    else
        return vim.fn.wordcount().words .. " words"
    end
end
```